# What are some Python libraries that support DCC file transfer?

Tags: python, irc

Are there any Python libraries that support DCC file transfers? If so, what are they, if not would it be within my ability as a novice python programmer to write my own?

Comment: [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.words.protocols.irc.html) has some DCC support; no idea if it is _good_ or not. If you're comfortable enough writing the IRC client, DCC support shouldn't be outside your comfort range.

Comment: How should we know what your abilities are?

Comment: @Wooble Well, I did say that I was a novice, and while I realize that's not all that informative, I would like to know if it's something that could realistically be done in a week or so, or if it would be a much larger project. Honestly, I'd rather have a library to handle if for me than try to code it myself.

Comment: @sarnold Took a look at Twisted, again though, it supports DCC _chat_ but not DCC file transfer.

Comment: are you sure? [`DccFileReceive`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.words.protocols.irc.DccFileReceive.html) documentation makes it look fairly complete, and [`DccSendProtocol`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.words.protocols.irc.DccSendProtocol.html), while under-documented, looks like it has enough implemented to support sending as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[irclib.py](http://python-irclib.sourceforge.net/) supports DCC connections.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at irclib, but while it supports DCC chat, it doesn't support binary transfer over DCC, which is really the crux of the situation.

Comment: @Lanny, look again; there are `dccsend` and `dccreceive` programs included in the source. :)